# Can we draw a graphic function in a different $x-y$-axis?

Tags: graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

Why $y$ and $x$ axis must be perpendicular? For example if we had a function $y=f(x)$ could we draw it on a coordinate system where $y$ and $x$ axis would have an angle of $30$ degrees?

Comment: When Rene Descartes devised his coordinate system he required only that the axes be non-parallel.

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/26400/26400-pdf.pdf?session_id=787f3f04243d96c696f2c23d8afe36bd1fa5c23a

Comment: Yes, you can take any kind of axis. We take $x-y$ axis perpendicular/orthogonal, because if we depict things of linear algebra in orthogonal axes/bases, things become easy to express. If we take non-orthogonal bases/axes, things would be same, but would take a slight difficult view.

Comment: [Oblique coordinate axes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ObliqueCoordinates.html) are often discussed in 1800s analytic geometry texts, of which many dozens (if not hundreds) are freely available on the internet (google-books, archive.org, etc.). This [19 August 2009 math-history-list post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6820106) archived at Math Forum may be of use.